# What if one module depends on another?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I have
    var hostswitch = require('./hostswitch.js')
    var publicAppInfo = require('./publicAppInfo.js')

Both of these are module.exports = function() etc.

However `publicAppInfo` needs to call `hostswitch` within itself. In fact, multiple functions that I would like to require would need to call `hostswitch` from within. Right now when I try it the way it is above, I simply receive a message that `hostswitch` is undefined.

Comment: Its simple, you call hostswitch in each of the file whch is dependent on it.
Or make every module export a function which takes hostswitch as parameter to return the actual export and when requiring them pass hostswitch as parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you should require hostswitch in each of the files or try this :

```
modules.export = function getPublicAppInfo (hostswitch) {return publicAppInfo;}
```

now when requiring

```
var hostswitch = require('./hostswitch');
var publicAppInfo = require('./publicAppInfo')(hostswitch);
```